# Jquery datatables button not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Here is my screenshot :
[image]

This is my following code:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script
<Script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'My button',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    alert( 'Button activated' );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

I'm trying to use this code from https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/custom. I dont why `my button` button didn't show up. I was wondering why this code is not working. Can anyone please tell me how to use 'jQuery DataTables Button'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

you have script error. try this one.

Screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/eazm0r

Answer (score 1):

You have not properly closed `script tag` you have a missing `>` from below `script tag`

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```